# GMSMarker not updating on initial load for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the latest google maps sdks for iOS  (1.10.3)

I plot a number of markers on a map when the user first comes to the map screen. 
These markers have custom marker icons.

When I run this code on the iPhone 5, the marker icons are never updated.
However, when I run this code on any phone after the iPhone 5 (iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+, iphone 6s etc) the marker icons are correctly loaded.

If I tap on the map at a random co-ordinate then the marker icons get updated.

I dont understand why this isn't working only for iPhone 5.

Comment: please post any related code about your marker update.

Comment: @goelv Any progress on this? I'm having the same issue with GMSPolygon.